# C++ check if a user in linux is a part/member of a specific group

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, authentication, group

I want to check if a user is for example
let's say `hello` group,

I have found these:

- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getgrouplist.3.html
- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getgroups.2.html
- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/group_member.3.html

But t doesn't help, what I want it to do is:

```cpp
if (!group_exists("hello")) {
    perror("group does not exist");
    exit(1);
}

if (!user_group_list.has("hello")) {
    perror("You are not in the hello group");
    exit(1);
}

...
```

Thanks for help in advance

**Update**

The people who are looking for this in the future:

```cpp
#include <grp.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

inline char *get_username(void) {
    struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(getuid());
    return pw ? pw->pw_name : NULL;
}

int get_group_count(void) {
    struct passwd *pw;
    gid_t *groups = (gid_t *)malloc(sizeof(*groups));
    const char *u = get_username();
    int ngroups;

    pw = getpwnam(u);
    if (pw == NULL) {
        perror("getpwnam");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    getgrouplist(u, pw->pw_gid, groups, &ngroups);
    free(groups);

    return ngroups;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int ngroups = get_group_count();
    struct passwd *pw;

    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cout << "Arg: group" << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    gid_t *groups = (gid_t *)malloc(sizeof(*groups) * get_group_count());
    if (groups == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Fetch passwd structure (contains first group ID for user). */

    pw = getpwnam(get_username());
    if (pw == NULL) {
        perror("getpwnam");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    /* Retrieve group list. */

    if (getgrouplist(get_username(), pw->pw_gid, groups, &ngroups) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getgrouplist() returned -1; ngroups = %d\n", ngroups);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Display list of retrieved groups, along with group names. */

    bool is_in = false;
    struct group *root = getgrnam(argv[1]);

    if (root == NULL) {
        free(groups);
        perror("getpwnam");
        return 1;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "ngroups = %d\n", ngroups);
    for (int j = 0; j < ngroups; j++) {
        if (groups[j] == root->gr_gid) {
            is_in = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << is_in << '\n';

    free(groups);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Even though it's ugly, I would suggest y'all take ths code and fix
it :) though it works

Comment: your code looks like python not C++

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number python is good for explaining what I want to do, it's not actually my code, I have no code in C++ for this, I am confused where to start or what to use

Comment: like pseudocode

Comment: you just have to add some `()` and replace `raise` with `throw` then you have a C++ example that demsontrates what you want to do. Its just not clear if you are looking for a solution in python or in c++

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number sure

Comment: What does "it doesn't help" mean? The answer here is to use `getgrouplist`. That's what it's for.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik but how am I supposed to know how big is ngroups?

Comment: The link you gave to `getgrouplist` explains how, specifically in the "RETURN VALUE" section.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm not a native english speaker, I am very confused by it: If the number of groups of which user is a member is less than or equal to *ngroups, then the value *ngroups is returned.

Comment: Should I pass -1 to *ngroups? at least I think that's how it works? but that is a very confusing way to say that

Comment: I think I need it to pass 0 as I see from "EXAMPLES"

Comment: That's not the only sentence in that section. There are two paragraphs there, that explain everything, and together with the last paragraph in the "DESCRIPTION" section it sufficiently explains this. It is true that knowing how to read and understand technical documentation is something that every C++ developer must learn how to do. I am not a native English speaker either, but, after some time, I learned. It takes time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243151/discussion-between-ari157-and-sam-varshavchik).

Comment: oops sorry, I will try to work it out

Comment: I am not able to figure it out, I keep getting segfaults when trying to get ngroups, but it's random too, hard to debug, I think I'll give up for now lol, if anyone knows, please notify me, I was literally doing the same basically as the EXAMPLES section for getgrouplist()...

Comment: I did not give up and got a very ugly example to work which I will port to my code: https://pastebin.com/fm2TzWjE